# Error code 401 in Java program

Tags: java, http-status-code-401, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website using a java program.
Until last night it was working perfect, but now the server returns error code 401.

HOWEVER, I can still see the pages that I want through my web browsers.
So, I don't know what is wrong? If the server add my IP to black list, so why can I see the URLs through the web browsers? If not, what else can cause 401 error?

Two more points:
There is no username and password for this site and authentication is based on my IP.

Also, I tried to change my user agent, and now I get Error 503.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely it could be blocking based on the user agent or request frequency based on your ip address.

Comment: In which case the server is misusing response code 401, as there is no way that the client could potentially authenticate. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.2

Comment: There are two issues. First, I can see the pages using the same computer. Also, I use a VPN account, and 6 of my computers who crawl a lot are blocked, but on the last one my program is still working.
I got confused. Because all of them using the same VPN, and in the same situation I can browse the html page that I want to see!

Comment: I tried to change my user agent using the following code, and now I received Error 503 <br>

URLcon = url.openConnection();
URLcon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)");

Answer (score 0):

401 is the HTTP error for *Unauthorized* and the reason you can see the site from your web browser and not from your java program could be that you set "Remember my user/password" in your browser and, of course, this option is not enabled in your Java Program.

Comment: My authorization is based on my IP not the username and password! And it used to work.
Also, as I said the program in working on other computers.